# Android intent filter for a non-launcher activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to add an intent filter for a special extension to my activity (non-launcher). But in file-managers, such as TotalCommander and others - the files are still not associated with my app, and Android doesn't suggest my app to open these file when i am trying to open them from file-manager. But when i moved my intent-filter - to the launcher activity -  everything start working fine. So i am wondering - the intent filter for extensions should be added only to the activity that is declared as a launcher in Manifest? Thanks

This is my intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myext"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `host`

```
<data android:host="*" />
```

> If a **host** is not specified for the filter, the port attribute and all
>   the **path attributes are ignored**.

Learn more **[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)**.